# Flutter: No implementation found for method connectDB on channel plugin.sqlconn.sql_conn/sql_conn

Tags: sql, sql-server, flutter, dart

Having trouble using the [`sql_conn`](https://pub.dev/packages/sql_conn) flutter plugin. I tested this out months ago and it was working fine, but now when I try to use their `connect` method it gives an error.

```
await SqlConn.connect(
        ip: "192.168.167.176",
        port: "1433",
        databaseName: "MyDatabase",
        username: "admin123",
        password: "Pass@123");
```

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method connectDB on channel plugin.sqlconn.sql_conn/sql_conn)

I've ran `flutter` `upgrade`/`outdated`/`get` but none of these worked.

I don't have the ability to create tags on stack overflow so if someone could please create a "sql_conn" tag so the package author can see it that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin seems to use native Android APIs, and so you will need to stop your runnig app and re-run it again in order that method channels used in it will actually link to Android SDK:

1. stop your app
2. optional: run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`
3. run it again

Comment: Yea somehow it's working now. I ran flutter clean, pub get, and I stopped/restarted the app. Not sure what order I did all this in